# Warning vs. error

Tags: java, compiler-construction, warnings

I had an annoying issue, getting a *"Possible loss of precision"* error when compiling my Java program on BlueJ (But from what I read this isn't connected to a specific IDE).

I was surprised by the fact that the compiler told me there is a possible loss of precision and wouldn't let me compile/run the program. **Why is this an error and not a warning** saying you might lose precision here, if you don't want that change your code?

The program runs just fine when I drop the float values; it wouldn't matter since there is no point (e.g [143.08, 475.015]) on my screen.

On the other hand when I loop through an ArrayList and in this loop I have an if clause removing elements from the ArrayList it runs fine, just throws an error and doesn't display the ArrayList [used for drawing circles] for a fraction of a second. This appears to me as a severe error but doesn't cause (hardly) any troubles, while I wouldn't want to have such a thing in my code at all.

What's the boundary?

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell without seeing the actual code...

Comment: I've always found the "Possible loss of precision" warning to be rather ironic...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: My question is not how to solve my specific problem, i did that already, rather why "Possible loss of precision" stops the compiler instead of showing a error message e.g

Comment: Because the precision error is caught at compile-time, but the ArrayList problem was only caught at runtime. Static analysis tools do exist which may have caught the ArrayList problem before running the code, but in general they can only say that there's *probably* an error, whereas the compiler must be much more definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error because the spec doesn't allow narrowing primitive conversions in an [Assignment Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2).

If you really want to assign a larger datatype to a smaller one, such as `double` to `float`, you must explicitly cast it.

Comment: Yes, good, that's why it's an error in the compiler -- because the compiler implements the language and the language says this is illegal. I suppose the bug is in the error message: "illegal narrowing conversion in assignment" is more precise but maybe just as inscrutable...

Answer (score 0):

It could lead to computation errors that are very hard to detect. So it's right that it is error - you do not want a program to give you result with unknown error in result.